# The command "nuget pack..." exited with code 1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I'm' trying to execute a post build event that builds a nuget package based on a .nuspec file. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. My post build event command line is:

```
nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -Symbols -Properties Configuration=$(ConfigurationName) -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

When I build my project, I get the following error:

```
The command "nuget pack C:\Users\user\Documebts\Code\BookProject\BookProject.Nuget\
BookProject.Nuget.csproj -Symbols -Properties Configuration=Debug 
-IncludeReferencedProjects" exited with code 1.
```

I'm not sure what's going on - I changed the Visual Studio build output to Diagnostic and found this:

```
>Using 'BookProject.nuspec' for metadata. (TaskId:44)
>Access to the path 'C:\BookProject.1.0.3.4.nupkg' is denied. (TaskId:44)
>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: The command "nuget pack C:\Users\user\Documebts\Code\BookProject\BookProject.Nuget\  BookProject.Nuget.csproj -Symbols -Properties Configuration=Debug -IncludeReferencedProjects" exited with code 1.
>Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. (TaskId:44)
>Done building target "PostBuildEvent" in project "Miw.Mshdf.Net.Nuget.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:72)
```

If I open up a command prompt and type in the post build event command, it works fine and builds the nuget package without any problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

According to the error code, your problem should be related to the access permission for the path "C:\". Please run your Visual Studio as administrator to make sure it has enough permissions to do any operations.

And make sure your current Windows user also has enough permissions to access the "C:\".

Answer (score 1):

The work around i used is

```
 1. Right click on solution -> manage nuget package for solution
 2. On top there is text "install missing packages" -> click restore
 3. Also i manually given the package sources in -tools ->Nuget package manager -> 
 package sources
 4. run VS 2013 in administrator mode and gave permission to the required folders
```